# "Я объединила монастыри в группы, относительно их отдалённости друг от друга..."?

Tags: выбор-слов, точное-словоупотребление

> Приблизительно понимая расположение интересующих нас памятников, я
>   объединила свои монастыри **в группы, относительно их отдалённости друг
>   от друга**, и **разбила передвижения** между ними **на несколько дней**.

Не знаю имени своей проблемы, но выделила то, что резануло.

Помогите, пожалуйста, поправить, если требуется-таки вмешательство.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, как-то странно звучит *в группы, относительно.* Я бы просто сказал *по отдалённости.* Вторая часть для меня не звучит однозначно неправильно, но немного мудрёно точно звучит. Поэтому предложил бы так изменить:

> *...в группы по их отдалённости друг от друга и отвела на путешествие по ним несколько дней.*

Answer (score 2):

Я сгруппировала монастыри по признаку их взаимной близости.

Comment: Саш, ну ты сказал. Взаимная близость. Скорее - территориальная.

Comment: Я понял так, что монастыри было решено посещать "кучками", чтобы от одного к другому было близко переезжать. А что, "близость одного монастыря к другому" (= их "взаимную близость") нельзя в _прямом_ смысле понимать?

Comment: Ну не знаю я. Потому и вопрошаю тута. А автору важно видеть, обо что народ спотыкается.

Answer (score 0):

Почти согласен с Alex_ander, только "признак" немножечко не то слово... 
И "взаимный" вызывает сомнения: ну что там за взаимность, если объектов больше двух?! Это не взатимность, это групповуха какая-то получается.

***Я сгруппировала монастыри по принципу их географической*** (или какой уж там, духовной?) ***близости.***